# Почему не работает 404.php в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Итак, есть тема на `WP`, там есть все нужные темплейты, плюс используется `Twig`. Пермалинки включены на `Post name`, сервер - `nginx`. Когда пытаюсь постучать на несуществующий адрес(например: `mysite.com/anything_what_does_not_exist`) - получаю результат работы файла `index.php` из корня темы. 
Вопрос: почему, и как полечить?

Comment: в корне шаблона есть  404.php ?

Comment: @Arsen Да, `404.php` есть в корне.

Comment: Если прямо на него тыкнуть(`mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/404.php`) - обнаружил 500 ошибку

Comment: внутри этого файла все удалите (после бекапа файла) и оставьте только  global $wp; Просто проверьте есть ли изменения ?

Comment: @Arsen Оставил только `global $wp;`, просто пустая страница.

Comment: Ну вот )) вот это и страница 404 но без дизайна )) если php ошибка бывает движок перекидывает на index.php. Надо найти что вызывает фатальную ошибку в этом файле

Comment: @Arsen `Call to undefined function.` Думаю, что в контексте данного вопроса проблема найдена и решена, оформите пожалуйста ответ, с радостью отмечу его как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переведу комментарии в полноценный ответ. 
В движке `Wordpress` при возникновении ошибки `404` система ищет в шаблоне файл `404.php` и, если есть такой файл, то движок сразу показывает пользователю данный файл (заглушку). Если такого файла нет или же в данном файле обнаружены системные ошибки (`PHP Error`) то система перебрасывает пользователя (хотя иногда бывают исключения) на `index.php` т.е пользователь видит основную, главную страницу сайта.